# iterating the xml for specific values

Tags: php, xml, database

I have an **xml** which is

```
<Classes>
<Class>

<ClassID>Ledger documents</ClassID>

<Rows>
<Row>
  <RowType>Header</RowType>
  <Cells>
    <Cell />
    <Cell>
      <Value>31 Jan 11</Value>
    </Cell>
  </Cells>
</Row>
<Row>
  <RowType>Section</RowType>
  <Title>Salary</Title>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <RowType>Row</RowType>
      <Cells>
        <Cell>
          <Value>Total</Value>
          <Attributes>
            <Attribute>
              <Value>7d05a53d</Value>
              <Id> Group</Id>
            </Attribute>
          </Attributes>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Value>200.56</Value>
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                  <Value>7d05a53d</Value>
                  <Id>group</Id>
                </Attribute>
              </Attributes>
            </Cell>
          </Cells>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <RowType>SummaryRow</RowType>
          <Cells>
            <Cell>
              <Value>Wages</Value>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
              <Value>434.78</Value>
            </Cell>
          </Cells>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <RowType>Section</RowType>
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <RowType>Row</RowType>
          <Cells>
            <Cell>
              <Value>Revenue</Value>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
              <Value>434.78</Value>
            </Cell>
          </Cells>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <RowType>Section</RowType>
      <Title>Costs</Title>
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <RowType>Row</RowType>
          <Cells>
            <Cell>
              <Value>Manpower</Value>
              <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                  <Value>2e277847</Value>
                  <Id>group</Id>
                </Attribute>
              </Attributes>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
              <Value>84.35</Value>
              <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                  <Value>2e277847</Value>
                  <Id>group</Id>
                </Attribute>
              </Attributes>
            </Cell>
          </Cells>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <RowType>SummaryRow</RowType>
          <Cells>
            <Cell>
              <Value>Total cost</Value>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
              <Value>84.35</Value>
            </Cell>
          </Cells>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <RowType>Section</RowType>
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <RowType>Row</RowType>
          <Cells>
            <Cell>
              <Value>Total Revenue</Value>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
              <Value>350.43</Value>
            </Cell>
          </Cells>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
    </Row>
  </Rows>
  </Class>
  </Classes>
```

The xml keeps on going for different group ids and its corresponding values.

I need to get only the different group ids and its values into the database table on local server.

Can somebody help me on this.

thanks

Comment: Can you post your entire XML , right now there is only a single group id and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through like this.. This is just an illustration code which works though , change the code as per your needs, also see the demo attached.

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file('users.xml');
echo "<pre>";
foreach($xml->Class->Rows->Row as $row)
{
   echo @$row->Cells->Cell[1]->Value."<br>";
    if(is_object($row->Rows->Row))
    {
        echo @$row->Rows->Row[0]->Cells->Cell[0]->Attributes->Attribute->Value."<br>";
        echo @$row->Rows->Row[0]->Cells->Cell[0]->Attributes->Attribute->Id."<br><br>";
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
31 Jan 11

7d05a53d
Group

2e277847
group
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/136167)

Comment: Hi, this works. But few issues...                                              I also want the date value from the xml [ <Value>31 Jan 11</Value> ] but while i use the above step, I am not getting the date value from the xml. Could you please help on that? Thanks

Comment: @user3462451, Modified the code and added a new demo , have a look.

Comment: Thanks Now the date value is also printed. Can you please also let me know how to insert into sql . I tried in the following:                                 $sql = "INSERT into tblname (id,date,details) values ('".$row->Rows->Row[0]->Cells->Cell[0]->Attributes->Attribute->Value."','".$row->Cells->Cell[1]->Value."','".$row->Rows->Row[0]->Cells->Cell[1]->Value."')";

Comment: ,The above query gets the date inserted in the first row followed by the id and its value. Why is it happening in that way? Any idea? Thanks

Comment: So you need all of them in a single row ?

Comment: yes , I need all of them to get inserted into a single row. Thanks

Comment: But `7d05a53d` and `2e277847` are two different ids .. they should also be in a single row ?

Comment: No i mean  7d05a53d, 31 Jan 11, 200.56 in a single row. followed by 2e277847,31 Jan 11, 84.35. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a classic case for `xpath`, which is like SQL for XML.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$attributes = $xml->xpath("//Attribute"); // select all <Attribute> no matter where in the tree
```

Now you can iterate:

```
foreach ($attributes as $a)
    echo "Value: $a->Value, Id: $a->Id" . PHP_EOL;
```

see it working: https://eval.in/135747

Comment: Hi, it was very useful. I just followed your steps and made small changes as per my needs which is like                                          foreach ($attributes as $a)
    echo "Value: $a->Value" . PHP_EOL; 
  
$cells= $xml->xpath("//Cell");  
    foreach ($cells as $c)
     echo "Value: $c->Value". PHP_EOL;

Comment: The output i got is Value: 7d05a53d
Value: 7d05a53d
Value: 2e277847
Value: 2e277847
Value: 
Value: 31 Jan 11
Value: Total
Value: 200.56
Value: Wages
Value: 434.78
Value: Revenue
Value: 434.78
Value: Manpower
Value: 84.35
Value: Total cost
Value: 84.35
Value: Total Revenue
Value: 350.43

Comment: Now what should i do to insert only the group id values Value: 7d05a53d and the values Value: 200.56 ( I dont want the headings like total, wages, Revenue )into my database table.thanks